# Genitiv bei Namen, die nur gesprochen auf s enden?

Tags: genitive, apostrophe

Beim Schreiben von Feedback zu einer Schülerarbeit kam mir gerade eine Frage:

Bei Namen wird im Genitiv ein s angehängt. Endet der Name auf s, ss, ß, tz, z, x wird stattdessen ein Apostroph gesetzt, also

> Schickards Rechenmaschine
> Leibniz' Rechenmaschine

So weit, so gut. Was ist aber mit Namen - im konkreten Fall ein französischer Name - die aufgrund eines stummen e am Ende zwar von der Aussprache auf s enden, nicht aber von der Schriftform her? Ist es

> Blaises Rechenmaschine

oder doch

> Blaise' Rechenmaschine

? (Ganz abgesehen davon, dass es inhaltlich korrekt Pascals Rechenmaschine sein müsste, weil Vor- und Nachname verwechselt wurden, aber das ist ein anderes Thema...)

Comment: *Blaise* endet tatsächlich nicht mit einem "s", sondern mit einem "stummen e". Da man den Namen französisch ausspricht (sonst würde er sich auch vorne sehr anders anhören...), fängt man das "e" wieder an zu hören, wenn es nicht mehr am Ende steht. Ich sehe eigentlich kein Problem dabei.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gemäß [§ 96 (1) des amtlichen Regelwerks](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6208#par96) gilt:

> **§ 96**
>
> Man setzt den Apostroph in drei Gruppen von Fällen.
>
> Dies betrifft
>
> (1) Eigennamen, deren Grundform (Nominativform) auf einen **s-Laut** (geschrieben: *-s, -ss, -ß, -tz, -z, -x, -ce*) endet. Sie bekommen im Genitiv den Apostroph, wenn sie nicht einen Artikel, ein Possessivpronomen oder dergleichen bei sich haben …

Die hinter **s-Laut** in Klammern angegebene Liste ist nicht vollständig. So gehört auch *-se* dazu, sofern das *e* stumm bleibt. Die Bedingung mit dem stummen *e* ist wichtig, wie im Beitrag [„Denises Auto und Denise’ Auto“](https://blog.leo.org/2017/11/29/denises-auto-und-denise-auto/) von *Fragen Sie Dr. Bopp!* erläutert wird:

> […] was stimmt, das heißt, wie man die Genitivform von *Denise* bildet, hängt davon ab, wie man den Namen ausspricht […]
>
> Bei ans Englische angelehnter Aussprache hat der Name zwei Silben und endet auf s, das heißt, *se* am Wortende wird als *s* ausgesprochen. Die Aussprache ist im Genitiv gleich wie im Nominativ. Dann schreibt man im Genitiv einen Apostroph:
>
> > Denise *[deni:s]* – Denise’ Auto *[deni:s auto]*

Kurzum, auch der Genitiv des einsilbrigen Namens *Blaise* wird aufgrund des s-Lauts *-se* mit stummem *e* mit einem Apostroph geschrieben:

> Blaise *[blɛz]* – Blaise’ Rechenmaschine *[blɛz ˈʁɛçn̩maˌʃiːnə]*

Comment: "Die hinter s-Laut in Klammern angegebene Liste ist nicht vollständig." steht da halt nicht, also da steht kein "usw." oder ähnliches, weil sich die Regel natürlich auf deutsche Wörter bezieht.

Comment: @HalvarF, auch der Rechtschreiberat hat nicht alle erdenklichen Fälle parat. Trotzdem geht es in § 96 (1) um **s-Laute**, und zu denen gehört nun einmal auch *-se* mit stummem *e*. Der Zusatz „mit stummem *e*“ ist hierbei wichtig, siehe etwa den Blog-Eintrag [„Denises Auto und Denise’ Auto“](https://blog.leo.org/2017/11/29/denises-auto-und-denise-auto/) bei *Fragen Sie Dr. Bopp!* Ich habe meine Antwort diesbezüglich erweitert.

Comment: Die Liste enthält aber sogar "-ce" als Beispiel was keinem (ur-)deutschen Wort entspricht, was den Punkt widerlegen dürfte @HalvarF. Das auf "-se" zu extrapolieren scheint offensichtlich.

Comment: Danke für die Links, genau so etwas hatte ich gesucht, aber nicht gefunden. Ich stimme zu, dass -se genau wie -ce behandelt werden dürfte.